# how to get current process image path from mini-filter kernel driver?

Tags: visual-studio, driver, wdk, windows-kernel, minifilter

I want to get current process path in my mini-filter kernel driver.I can get current process with `PEPROCESS peProcess = IoGetCurrentProcess()` and can get process full filename(that include path) with `ZwQueryInformationProcess`.
But i want just get path (without filename).
I use visualstudio 2019 & latest SDK/WDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

`ZwCreateFile`(DesiredAccess=FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES) → file HANDLE

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntcreatefile

`ZwQueryInformationFile`(FileInformationClass=FileNameInformation) → FILE_NAME_INFORMATION structure

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile

> "If the full path and file name are returned, the string will begin
>   with a single backslash, regardless of its location. Thus the file
>   C:\dir1\dir2\filename.ext will appear as `\dir1\dir2\filename.ext`"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile#remarks

(Then you strip off the leaf filename by finding the last backslash.)

`ZwClose`(the HANDLE)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwclose